# How to use sub queries with multiple (different) columns returned

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, neo4j

I couldn't really find a good enough title, I'll admit. This is going to be difficult but I'll try to explain my situation as best I can.

I've run into an issue where the only possible solution for me seems to be to use two separate cypher queries, where the results of the first query are used to initiate a match in the second query, to get the job done. I feel my problem is unique because as far as I've tried, I can't seem to get the WITH or the UNION clauses to give me the desired results.

What I'm trying to do is the following.

```
MATCH (n1)--(n2) WHERE n2.name="something" WITH n2
MATCH (n2)--(n3) WHERE n3.name="something_else" WITH n3 as to_be_returned, n3 as to_continue
MATCH (to_continue)--(n4) WHERE n4.name="something"
RETURN to_be_returned as FirstPartResults, n4 as SecondPartResults
```

What I'm trying to do here is, when I get to the end of the first two matches, I wish to keep whatever Neo4j has matched as a separate piece of information (n3), and at the same time move on and use that to make further matches to narrow down all the way to n4, which when ends, returns both n3 and n4. But, what I find Neo4j does is, it gives the correct results for n4, but the results for n3 are always the same as n4 - ie, it messes with "to_be_returned" whereas I want it to go ahead and mess with "to_continue" and leave "to_be_returned" alone.

The reason I want this to be done in a single query, is because I am trying to avoid pagination problems if I break it down into two separate queries.

I've also tried the following using UNION ALL:

```
MATCH (n1)--(n2) WHERE n2.name="something" WITH n2
MATCH (n2)--(n3) WHERE n3.name="something_else"
RETURN n3.name as "to_be_returned"

UNION ALL

MATCH (n1)--(n2) WHERE n2.name="something" WITH n2
MATCH (n2)--(n3) WHERE n3.name="something_else" WITH n3
MATCH (n3)--(n4) WHERE n4.name="something"
RETURN n4 as SecondPartResults
```

This gives me the following error:

```
All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names
```

Changing the column names to be the same, gives results exactly like the original query without using UNION.

**EDIT**

For some reason, I am unable to create and share a console URL, so ill just paste the CREATE statement here along with the MATCH query.

```
create 
(_6:Crew  {name:"Neo"}),
(_7:Crew  {name:"Morpheus"}),
(_8:Crew  {name:"Trinity"}),
(_9:Crew:Matrix  {name:"Cypher"}),
(_10:Matrix  {name:"Agent Smith"}),
(_11:Matrix  {name:"The Architect"}),
(_12:USER  {name:"Sherlock Holmes"}),
(_13:USER  {name:"John Watson"}),
_6-[:KNOWS]->_7,
_6-[:LOVES]->_8,
_6-[:FRIENDS]->_13,
_7-[:KNOWS]->_8,
_7-[:KNOWS]->_9,
_8-[:FRIENDS]->_12,
_9-[:KNOWS]->_10,
_10-[:CODED_BY]->_11

MATCH (c1:Crew) WHERE c1.name="Morpheus" WITH c1 MATCH (c1)--(c2:Crew) WITH c2 AS to_be_returned, c2 AS to_continueMATCH (to_continue)--(u:USER) WHERE u.name="Sherlock Holmes" RETURN to_be_returned AS FirstPart, to_continue AS SecondPart;
```

Both First and Second Part results come out to be the same. The first part should contain the results Trinity and Neo, and the second part should just have Trinity.

Comment: Here is a [console example](http://neo4j-console-20.herokuapp.com/r/vz6mg6), could you do something similar and explain what data you want the query to return? Is it a `OPTIONAL MATCH` kind of problem, i.e. the 'second part' may not match anything? Or what do you mean "it messes with to_be_returned"?

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example? You can use collect to put certain information into a collection without changing the cardinality of your statement. What about merging all your match statements into one? Or looking up your nodes with name upfront and then doing (optional) matches on them?

Comment: I have edited the question with a sample dataset and a sample query which is giving me the wrong output. Hopefully it will be clearer now.
@jjaderberg I dont think its an optional match problem.

Michael Hunger I have tried using collect(to_be_resturned) but it leads to the same problem. I haven't tried your other suggestions, but i was hoping my edit would make the query clearer.
Btw, Thanks for taking time to respond. Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first collect the matched c2 and assign the collection as "to_be_returned", then continue to further match the original c2 instead of the alias "to_continue"

```
MATCH (c1:Crew) WHERE c1.name='Morpheus'
WITH c1
MATCH (c1)--(c2:Crew)
WITH collect(c2) AS to_be_returned
MATCH (c2)--(u:USER)
WHERE u.name='Sherlock Holmes'
RETURN to_be_returned AS FirstPart, collect(c2) AS SecondPart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Firstly it works! But theres a slight issue. At the end of it, I want to be able to paginate the results ie, use SKIP and LIMIT. I'm given to understand that SKIP, LIMIT options cannot be used on collections. So, is there any way by which I could LIMIT to_be_returned to some number and run the second part of the query on those limited results?

Comment: Ive managed to solve my pagination issues. Your answer works perfectly! Thanks! The mistake I was making was along with 'WITH collect(c2)' I also carried forward 'c2' separately.
Thanks Lisa, jjaderberg, and Michael!!